# Clang is not compiling code for platforms other than x86

Tags: c++, arm, llvm, clang

I'm under Ubuntu 12.04 x86 64 bit, I have compiled a 32 bit version of `llvm/clang` from the official svn repository successfully.

I'm now trying to compile c++ code for ARM, at this point i don't care about platform versions like `armv5` vs `armv7a`, I'm focusing on how the platform switch works for `clang`:

```
llvm-config --targets-built
ARM CellSPU CppBackend Hexagon Mips MBlaze MSP430 NVPTX PowerPC Sparc X86 XCore
```

but the following command doesn't work

```
clang++ -arch arm soft.cpp -o soft_ARM
```

the output is

```
clang-3: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-arch arm'
```

I have also tried gcc-like variants or other combinations like `-arch=arm`, `-arch=armv7a`, `-march=armv5` but nothing seems to work.

After reading some docs i noticed that clang works for ARM only under MAC OS X / Darwin and it's not supposed to work for ARM under other OS.

How i can compile for ARM with clang and what the output of `llvm-config --targets-built` is really about ?

Comment: i have just compiled a 64 bit version of clang and the behaviour it's always the same as before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

-arch is darwin-only feature. You should use -target  on non-darwin platforms. Alternatively, compile llvm/target specifying target triplet or create a link from clang to -clang. In your case the target triplet would be arm-none-linux-gnueabi

Comment: not working, `clang-3: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi'`

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be -target arm-none-linux-gnueabi

Comment: 1 mini step forward but it keeps not working `/usr/bin/as: unrecognized option '-mfloat-abi=softfp'
clang-3: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @user1797612, clang driver is unlikely to pick up the right toolchain for you. Chances are, you have to do everything manually. Therefore, try `clang -cc1 -triple arm-linux-gnueabihf -emit-llvm -o - ...` and pipe its output to `llc -mtriple=...`, and then use an appropriate `as` and `ld` versions from your cross-binutils.

Comment: @user1797612, clang does not know where to find cross-binutils for you. So, you need to put clang (or create softlink) into the bin directory of the sysroot root. Alternatively, you might have luck with -sysroot or -gcc-toolchain options.

Comment: I was convinced that clang was distributed with all the C/C++ libraries that i need to use it. After reading both your replies and searching for headers paths i found nothing in the llvm/clang dirs: where i can get the right C/C++ library for ARM for using it with clang ?

Comment: It depends on your platform :) E.g. on ARM you can use ordinary libc, or eglibc, or uclibc, or newlib, or you can run stuff on bare-metal... It's hard to say something definite without knowing your purposes.